# Having trouble with THREE.OrbitControls

Tags: three.js

I create objects on the fly and they have large coordinate numbers for example [1000000,1000000,1000000].

Now when I navigate to the object via setting the position of THREE.PerspectiveCamera I see the objects but rotation does not work.

I'm setting

```
controls.rotateSpeed = 0.000001;
controls.zoomSpeed = 0.0000001;
controls.keyPanSpeed = 0.000001;

camera.position.set(1000910, 1000325, 1000102);
controls.target.set(1000202, 1000325, 1000063);
```

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zxszy20g/

I'd like that OrbitControls would start rotating around the new assigned position similarly as it does in the original example http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having had some problems myself with large models that were improperly scaled, camera positions zoomed out too far and so forth, I wonder if your large coordinates are causing the issue ?

Comment: Coordinates are part of the issue. I'm guessing that default target (0,0,0) does not work with large coordinates so one would have to increase the target for it to work properly. Unfortunately plainly setting the target does not work.

When using http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit moving with arrows changes cameras position and controls.target position also changes (but rotation remains in working order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your `rotateSpeed` so low? I've just set `controls.rotateSpeed = 0.1;` and put the target near to the camera (e.g. `controls.target.set(camera.position.x+500, camera.position.y, camera.position.z+500);`) and the rotation works quite well in your jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't even know... I played around with different combinations of variables to get it working. Guess I was too impatient. Thanks!